# C# ReadXML not sequencing out the element values into the correct columns

Tags: c#, xml, model-view-controller, xml-parsing

I have an issue where I am not able to get each element value to populate the correct column from a HttpWebResponse. Just so you know, I have been trawling the net for the past week on this issue, tried many different approaches and they end in much the same way.

My Input Stream looks like:

```
   <results>
    <result inum="848023000000101">
    <field name="inum">848023000000101</field>
    <field name="switchcallid">00001001011520423332</field>
    <field name="startedat">2018-03-07T14:02:16.636</field>
    <field name="duration">36</field>
    <field name="otherparties">1320 (Johan R), 1322 (Craig Smythe)</field>
    </result>
    <result inum="848023000000103">
    <field name="inum">848023000000103</field>
    <field name="switchcallid">00001001941520500491</field>
    <field name="startedat">2018-03-08T11:28:15.694</field>
    <field name="duration">25</field>
    <field name="otherparties">1323 (Barry Celliers), 1320 (Johan R)</field>
    </result>
    </results>
```

My Controller code looks like:

```
 using (HttpWebResponse response = APIrequestStream.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {   var file = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
                var descendants = file.Descendants();
                foreach (var descendant in descendants)
                {
                //loop through each elements of descendant
                    foreach (var element in descendant.Elements().Elements())
                    {
                        List<Tuple<string>> Headers = new List<Tuple<string>>();
                    //assiging of element name as propertyName
                        string propertyName = element.FirstAttribute.Value;
                        Headers.Add(Tuple.Create(propertyName));
                    }
                    foreach (var element in descendant.Elements().Elements())
                    {
                        List<Tuple<string>> Rows = new List<Tuple<string>>();
                        string PropertyValue = element.Value;
                        datatbl.Rows.Add(PropertyValue);
                    }
                }
```

My view Looks like:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th style="font-size:40px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center">iNUM</th>
                <th style="font-size:40px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center">UCID</th>
                <th style="font-size:40px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center">Start Date</th>
                <th style="font-size:40px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center">Duration</th>
                <th style="font-size:40px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center">Participants</th>
            </tr>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Rows.Count; i++)
{            <tr>
    <td style="font-size:100px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;">@Model.Rows[i][0]</td>
    <td style="font-size:100px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;">@Model.Rows[i][1]</td>
    <td style="font-size:100px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;">@Model.Rows[i][2]</td>
    <td style="font-size:100px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;">@Model.Rows[i][3]</td>
    <td style="font-size:100px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;">@Model.Rows[i][4]</td>
</tr>
    }
        </table>
```

And my result looks like this on the page:

[image: Screenshot of output]

I need to format the output so each value is in it's own column.
Please can someone assist or direct me to a good solution.

Comment: this is because you are adding each value in a new row in the first column. Your other columns are blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing something too complicated.

```
var file = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream());

foreach (var result in file.Root.Elements())
{
    var values = result
        .Elements() // field
        .Select(e => e.Value)
        .ToArray();

    datatbl.Rows.Add(values);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander Petrov that hit the nail on the head.